# Copy rows based on cell value and paste on a new sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

Check This

[image]

I need a help. I want to copy whole cell from A sheet name "Components" only if value in Column C is > 0 to a new Sheet name "Load list"

Can someone please give me the macro code for this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your first tries. StackOverflow is definitively not a "Do it for me site".

Comment: use `Autofilter` method instead of looping

Answer (score 1):

on your new sheet you can add this condition the cell or range of cells:

=IF(Components!C5>0,Components!A5)

where C5 has thevalue to compare, and A5 has the value copy if the condition happens.

Comment: But that formula copies something (the value `False`) if `Components!C5<=0`, which is not what the OP asks for.

Answer (score 0):

Right in my swing!

The formula given by @sweetkaos will work fine, in case you want to replicate the data as it is with blanks where data is not found.

I will imagine a slightly more complicated situation. I am assuming you want just one line in the next format as is shown in your image.

Also conveniently assuming the following:
a. both sheets have fixed start points for the lists 
b. 2 column lists - to be copied and pasted, with second column having value
c. Continuous, without break source list 
d. basic knowledge of vba, so you can restructure the code

Here is the code. Do try to understand it line by line. Happy Excelling!

```
Sub populateLoadList()    
'declaring range type variables
Dim rngStartFirstList As Range, rngStartLoadList As Range

'setting values to the range variables
'you must change the names of the sheets and A1 to the correct starts of your two lists

Set rngStartFirstList = Worksheets("Name_of_your_fist_sheet").Range("A1")

Set rngStartLoadList = Worksheets("Name_of_your_second_sheet").Range("A1")


Do While rngStartFirstList.Value <> ""
  If rngStartFirstList.Offset(1, 0).Value < 0 Then

     Range(rngStartFirstList, rngStartFirstList.Offset(0, 1)).Copy      

     rngStartLoadList.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

     Application.CutCopyMode = False

     Set rngStartLoadList = rngStartLoadList.Offset(1, 0)

   End If

   Set rngStartFirstList = rngStartFirstList.Offset(1, 0)

Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Half of your `Offset(1, 0)`s should probably be `Offset(0, 1)`s (or, more likely based on the question, `Offset(0, 2)`s)

Comment: And you should declare `rngStartFirstList` as a `Range` rather than a `Variant`.  (It will still work as is, but it is usually better practice to explicitly declare variables to the appropriate type rather allow them to be set as `Variant`.)  And `Range(rngStartFirstList, ...` should be `Worksheets("Name_of_your_fist_sheet").Range(rngStartFirstList, ...` to avoid the code crashing if "Name_of_your_fist_sheet" was not the active sheet.

Comment: @YowE3K thanks, there was one typo in the copy statement, and a bad assumption in variable declaration

Answer (score 0):

Basically what i want is ... if Value on C is >0 i want whole column 10 copied to that new sheet .... not only that cell